# Editing a key field from composite primary key showing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Model :-**

```
  public partial class tblMake
    {
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Display(Name = "Company Code")]
    public string Company_Code { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Make Code")]
    public string Make_Code { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60)]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "Remark")]
    public string Remark { get; set; }
   }
```

**View :-**

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Company_Code)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text" style="float: left; width: 200px; ">Make Code :</label>

        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Make_Code, new { style = "width:200px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Make_Code)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text" style="float: left; width: 200px; ">Description :</label>

        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { style = "width:600px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text" style="float: left; width: 200px; ">Remark :</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remark, new { style = "width:800px;height: 150px;" })


            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remark)
        </div>
    </div>
```

When i try to edit 'Make Code';which is a part of composite primary key,it comes with the error (line breaks inserted for readability) :-

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException:
  Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).
  Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
  Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

Can anyone explain what to do?

Comment: EF maps primary key values and object references and doesn't allow you to change the key for the same object instance. I think you must first delete the object from the context and the re-attach with the new primary key value before saving.

Comment: why they had to make it complicated. Thanks for the response.